# Wordpress: custom meta tag listing

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Using Wordpress, I am trying to write a php script that, given a certain post ID, returns all the related custom tags (also named custom terms, i. e. these words that I can use to meta describe a post and are category-independent. For example, in [this page](http://www.lyra.it/blog/mercury-rising-codice-mercury-1998) the custom terms are "passabile" and "thriller").

Is there a way to do that, possibly some WP-method that takes care of custom tag revisions?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Use the `get_post_meta()` function.  Say your tag is named 'custom_terms', you can do this:

```
$terms = get_post_meta( $id, 'custom_terms' );
```

If you are already on the post that you want to get that information for you can do:

```
$terms = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'custom_terms' );
```

See here:  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta

`$terms` will be an array containing all of the values.

**EDIT:**  If you are talking strictly about the tags of a post, you can [try this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags):

```
$tags = get_the_tags();
```

This returns an array of tag objects that you can access by looping through them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... All I get, leaving the custom_terms variable empty, is this:  ["_edit_last"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  ["_edit_lock"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(12) "1414253683:1"
  }
} Are we talking about the same terms?

Comment: We're probably not, but you weren't clear on your post.  Are these meta data of the post?  Are they tags?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<?php 
$id = //post id
$taxonomy = //your custom texonomy name
get_the_term_list( $id, $taxonomy ); 
?>
```

for more info about [get_the_term_list](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list)

Comment: Good call - I still am not sure if the OP is looking for terms, tags, metadata, etc., and forgot he might be talking about the taxonomy terms